# How to convert a JSON file to CSV with 15,000 tweets using Python 3

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, tweepy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFYCv.png)I have collected 15,000 Arabic tweets for research purposes using tweepy streamer API. the tweets were saved in 37 JSON files and finally copied into one JSON file. I am trying to convert it to CSV by using this script: https://github.com/HMukdadi/json-csv-converter
but I keep getting 

 "Error loading file ... exiting: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 7478)
" 
 also, I am a linguist and I don't have a solid programming background :).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k270b.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-) Do all of the lines in your JSONs have the same format throughout? The error is saying that it's seeing something that it doesn't expect on line 3. I recommend cutting a JSON down until it is just a few lines but gives you an error, then creating a [MCVE](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) to help you and us troubleshoot.

Comment: Your file doesn't look like regular JSON from the picture, as entries are written in JSON but separated by line breaks. For parsing this format, you can use the [jsonlines parser](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), after removing the blank lines.

Comment: Also please do not include text as a picture, but instead please copy it into your question as text or code

Answer (score 0):

Its normal because the json file contains many json object that should be in a JSON array or in a parent json object.

Post 2 or 3 lines if you want and I will write for you a script that accept your type of input , or :add [ at the beginning ] at the end and  , after each } except the last and the script will work for you

This script converts you json file that is like the sample into valid json array that will work with the script in the git repo ( tested )

```
import sys

print("[")
with open(sys.argv[1]) as files:
    lines=files.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if(line!="\n"):

            print(line)
        else:
            print(",")
    files.close()
print("]")
```

execute it :
`python3 file.py [yourJsonFile] >> newJsonFile.json`

then execute the json-csv-converter.py with the newJsonFile.json

[image]

Suppose that you have SAMPLE.json file:
[image]

Just execute the script :

[image]

Then execute the json-csv-converter.py :

[image]

Comment: it's ok the script is tested

Comment: I am really thankful but I do not know how to do that. if you don\t mind is there a way that I can contact you.

Comment: I have done the same exact thing but I run into another error: Error loading file ... exiting: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: upload the file and i will try